# Test a string for non-numerical characters Luhn Test Java

Tags: java, string, integer

How do I test the input String for non numerical characters and then return false if there are non-numerical characters found.

```
private static boolean luhnTest(String number){
    int s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
    String reverse = new StringBuffer(number).reverse().toString();

    for(int i = 0 ;i < reverse.length();i++)
    {
        int digit = Character.digit(reverse.charAt(i), 10);
        if(i % 2 == 0){//this is for odd digits, they are 1-indexed in the algorithm
            s1 += digit;
        }
        else
        {//add 2 * digit for 0-4, add 2 * digit - 9 for 5-9
            s2 += 2 * digit;
            if(digit >= 5)
            {
                s2 -= 9;
            }
        }
    }
    return (s1 + s2) % 10 == 0;
}
```

Comment: so doesn't this work ?

Comment: So you are able to put down a complicated test that checks for "Luhn CRC"; but you are unable to first check the same string if it contains non-digits? Hint: try doing prior research, for example searching for certain keywords; pointing out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java easily?

Comment: This is just code that is freely available on the internet, I did not create it myself.

Comment: You should get better sources for copying, then. This is not a high quality piece of code. That thing with the string buffer and the reverse is not really needed. Better yet, put in the effort to learn to program yourself. It will pay in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be a regular expression (`"\d*"`), see the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. Another one, but a little bit smelly, would simply be to use `Integer.parseInt (...)` (or `Long.parseLong( ...)` ) and catch the Exception.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the Integer.parseInt(...) because that's what I thought and I tried it but I must have either passed a wrong argument or put it in the wrong place (hence my need to ask this question).  If you could tell me where it fits in the code I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `public boolean isDigit(String something) { try { return Long.parseLong( something) >= 0; } catch(NumberFormatException e) { return false; } }`

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the digits, and see if anything is left:

```
public class DigitsCheck{

         public static boolean isOnlyDigits(String input) {
             return (input.replaceAll("\\d", "").length() == 0);
         }

         public static void main(String []args){
            System.out.println(isOnlyDigits("abc123"));
            System.out.println(isOnlyDigits("123"));
         }
    }
```

Produces

```
false
true
```